# Allow only admins to write data - Firebase Realtime Database - Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to give **.write** permission only to those authenticated users with **isAdmin:true**
Below is the structure of Database.
In the **clients**(users) node **uid** is the Firebase generated auth uid.

```
{
  "clients" : {
    "-M8bGQaB....." : {
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "uid" : 5gvR1GzT...
     }
   },
  "products" : {
    "-M81GzT....." : {
     "productName": "Product 1"
      },
    "-M81GzT....." : {
     "productName": "Product 2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to more clearly explain what isn't working the way you expect.  Rules don't mean anything without code that's going to access the database.  Since you tagged with Cloud Functions, please also say how that product is involved here.

Comment: Hey!
The Cloud Function tag was added by mistake.
Removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current data structure there is no way to look up the user profile in the security rules, as security rules can't search across all users.

That's why the proper data structure to store user uses their UID as the key. In your case that'd look like:

```
  "clients" : {
    "5gvR1GzT..." : {
      "isAdmin" : true
     }
   },
```

---

With this JSON, you can then only allow users to write a product when the `isAdmin` property for their UID is set to `true` with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "products": {
      "$productid": {
        ".write": "root.child('clients').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank,
Is there any way I could point a wildcard inside .child() ?
For example, root.child($id).val() - something like this?

Comment: No, as the rules engine has no way to know what node to use there. Any operation that would require Firebase to scan a lot of nodes for a rule is not going to scale, so those are not allowed. That's why I had to change your data model in my answer.